# How to find COM ports on Windows

Tags: windows, serial-port

I work with a bunch of embedded devices that use serial ports to connect to my windows machine.  I can run `mode` to find out which COM port I've just connected (or disconnected), but it's a pain to scroll back through all the output and find what's changed.

Is there an easier solution that uses the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following little script that runs `mode` and sorts the results.  Launch it, it stays open and you can hit `Enter` at any time to refresh the list.  It's simple, yes, but its yours to tailor any way you see fit: [*]

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# List COM ports on one line
#
# SYNOPSIS:
#   ListPorts.sh

MODE="/c/Windows/System32/mode.com"

list_ports() {
  PORTS_W=$(${MODE} | grep "Status for device COM" | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed s/:// | sort -V )
  echo ${PORTS_W}
}

while [ 1 ] ; do
  echo -n "Available COM ports are "
  list_ports
  echo -n "Hit [Enter] to refesh the list or ^C to quit: "
  read
done
```

*[*] Left as an exercise for the reader: just use `sed` to trim the string rather than `awk ... |  sed ...`*

### sample output:

```
Available COM ports are COM4 COM9 COM18 COM19
Hit [Enter] to refesh the list or ^C to quit:
```